# How to get Page/Post Featured Images to show on Twitter Card? Hugo (Academic Theme)

Tags: html, github, twitter, markdown, hugo

I have been having difficulty getting Twitter Cards to work for my posts featured images. The featured images appear for post url's on both Facebook and Linkedin, yet I can't get the twitter card to work.

I have tried reviewing the twitter card code in the academic header and also by following the Hugo documentation. I am unsure if its something that missing or overlooking? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I found this code in the **academic header.html partial**, yet I am still unsure as to why it is not working:

```
  {{ $featured_image := (.Resources.ByType "image").GetMatch "*featured*" }}
  {{ $og_image := "" }}
  {{ $twitter_card := "summary_large_image" }}
  {{ if $featured_image }}
    {{ $og_image = $featured_image.Permalink }}
  {{ else if .Params.header.image }}
    {{ $og_image = printf "img/%s" .Params.header.image | absURL }}
  {{ else if .Site.Params.sharing_image }}
    {{ $og_image = printf "img/%s" .Site.Params.sharing_image | absURL }}
  {{ else if .Site.Params.avatar }}
    {{ $og_image = (printf "img/%s" site.Params.avatar) | absURL }}
    {{ $twitter_card = "summary" }}
  {{ else }}
    {{ $og_image = "img/icon-192.png" | absURL }}
    {{ $twitter_card = "summary" }}
  {{ end }}
  <meta property="twitter:card" content="{{ $twitter_card }}">
  {{ with .Site.Params.twitter }}
  <meta property="twitter:site" content="@{{ . }}">
  <meta property="twitter:creator" content="@{{ . }}">
  {{ end }}
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ .Site.Title }}">
  <meta property="og:url" content="{{ .Permalink }}">
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{ if not .IsHome }}{{ .Title }} | {{ end }}{{ .Site.Title }}">
  <meta property="og:description" content="{{ $desc }}">
  {{- with $og_image }}<meta property="og:image" content="{{ . }}">{{end}}
  <meta property="og:locale" content="{{ .Site.LanguageCode | default "en-us" }}">
  {{ if .IsPage }}
  {{ if not .PublishDate.IsZero }}<meta property="article:published_time" content="{{ .PublishDate.Format "2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00" | safeHTML }}">
  {{ else if not .Date.IsZero }}<meta property="article:published_time" content="{{ .Date.Format "2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00" | safeHTML }}">{{ end }}
  {{ if not .Lastmod.IsZero }}<meta property="article:modified_time" content="{{ .Lastmod.Format "2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00" | safeHTML }}">{{ end }}
  {{ else }}
  {{ if not .Date.IsZero }}<meta property="og:updated_time" content="{{ .Date.Format "2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00" | safeHTML }}">{{ end }}
  {{ end }}
```

The twitter card validator log says the following:

```
INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  18 metatags were found
INFO:  twitter:card = summary_large_image tag found
INFO:  Card loaded successfully
```

Yet, no image appears. Any help or tips on resolving this would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Can you share a specific live URL?

Comment: @AndyPiper Sure, here it is [url](https://www.dylangrimeslarkin.me/post/blog/pint-of-science-redesigning-healthcare/). (Also GitHub [repo](https://github.com/dylangrimesxo/dylangrimeslarkin) if necessary).

Comment: the `og:image` tag contains a relative URL, not a complete one. Twitter requires a full URL including http(s) and domain.

Comment: @AndyPiper if I set the ```og:image``` tag to my website URL will the same image not be used for all pages. Or can I set it so my baseURL and the page featured image are used in the ```og:image``` tag? And thanks for your help

Comment: You'll need to set it to add the baseURL to the start of the relative URL for the image for the individual post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens the problem I experienced was due to an incorrect `baseURL` in the config.toml file in Hugo. Once, I corrected this error, the Twitter summary card began to appear as normal.

Comment: I think I'm experiencing the same problem. Can you please elaborate in what way `baseURL` was incorrect and how you have solved it? Thanks!